# Как парсить игру в Steam?

Tags: python

Есть скрипт на Python, который парсит жанр игры с этой страницы: 
https://store.steampowered.com/

Вот что код выводит:

```
<span>Приключение,</span>
<span>Point & Click,</span>
<span>Инди,</span>
<span>Для одного игрока,</span>
<span>Головоломка,</span>
<span>Глубокий сюжет,</span>
<span>Фэнтези,</span>
<span>Отличный саундтрек,</span>
<span>Атмосфера,</span>
<span>Шедевр,</span>
<span>Юмор,</span>
<span>Рисованная графика,</span>
```

А вот что он должен выводить:

```
<span>Жанр: Приключение, Point & Click, Инди, Для одного игрока, Головоломка, Глубокий сюжет, Фэнтези, Отличный саундтрек, Атмосфера, Шедевр, Юмор,</span>
```

Как сделать лишь одно слово ЖАНР и через запятую перечислять все жанры? С любой ссылкой на игру из стима.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_link(html):
    a = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    shanr = soup.find('div', class_='glance_tags popular_tags').find_all('a', class_='app_tag')
    for w in shanr:
        a.append(w.text.strip())
    print('<span>Жанры: ', end='')
    for ress in a:
         print(ress + ', ', end='')
    print('</span>')
```

Поясню: в функции `print()` параметр `end` означает символ, который мы будем ставить в конце каждого вызова этой функции, по умолчанию имеет значение `\n`, поэтому у нас каждый отдельный `print()` пишется с новой строки. 
Когда мы присваеваем этому параметру пустое значение, после вывода мы не переносим каретку на новую строку, следовательно вывод будет происходить в одну строку.